# Search max and min value in Date Range cols

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df.

[image]

The index, 'Date', is dt and is continuous daily data.  I have two other dt cols, 'startDate' and 'endDate'.  For each row I need to find the max and min of 'Value1' between startDate and endDate. Each 'startDate' and 'endDate' is in the index.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly I think you want to join the df to itself where the Date column is between startDate and endDate. Once you have this you can then aggregate over your index, returning the min and max values as desired.